# Sendmail on Raspberry, how change the sender mail address ?

Tags: linux, email, raspberry-pi, sendmail

I installed sendmail on my raspberry. I tested if sending mail is ok but when I execute this command :

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v anexistinggmailaccount@gmail.fr
```

I get this error :

```
<pi@raspberrypi>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found
```

I understand I must change the sender mail but I don't find where I must change this configuration.I didn't find the solution after several internet searches...

Comment: Do you use fixed IP address? Is you sendmail program provided by sendmail pachage or postfix, exim, ..?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not used to deploy mails servers. The public ip of my raspberry is fixed yes. I only installed the package sendmail (sudo apt-get install sendmail), should I install other packages ? Or do I miss a sendmail  configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Change you hostname (as reported by `hostname --fqdn`) to name with DNS `A` record pointing to you fixed IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! where I must add the hostname param ? I didn't see protocol param when I show the man of sendmail ("man sendmail") ..

Comment: It is "system wide" setting.  Which Linux/Unix distribution do you use?

Comment: I use Raspbian 8 (jessie) (Its on a raspberry pi)

Comment: raspberrypi.org forums: hostname change -> https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=125373